# Simulating a button click within ascx page

Tags: c#, sharepoint, onclick

I need to simulate a button click on my ascx page. The user firstly clicks on a button on the service home page which links to a certain service and a new window opens for that related service. If they are not logged in it directs them to the login page. A querystring is sent with it to keep note of what service they had originally clicked. When the user then logs in they are redirected back to the services page and the querystring of what they clicked on before is sent also.

I have up to this point working fine. The problem is that when I'm redirected back to the online services page I need to simulate an onclick event which will open the new window. I cant click on an the onclick method for the button as there is none, everything is done dynamically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought the easiest way to achieve what it sounds like you're trying to do is in the code behind for your Online Services Page check to see whether the query string contains the url for the service they clicked on before you sent them to the login page, if it does then add some javascript to run on start up which launches the pop-up (using the ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx).

If you absolutely have to fire the click event you can also do that from your javascript by finding the button you want to click by it's ClientId (using getElementById) and then calling the javascript click() method on it. Here is an example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp